# XML parsing: line 1, character 2923, semicolon expected in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Declare @InputData nvarchar(max)
set @InputData ='5B 71-00-01 DISSA 001,03/26/2018 15:50:08,03/26/2018 16:50:08,41871;5B 71-00-01 DISSA 002,03/26/2018 16:50:08,03/26/2018 17:50:08,41872;5B 71-00-01 DISSA 003,03/26/2018 17:50:08,03/26/2018 18:50:08,41873;5B 71-00-01 DISSA 004,03/26/2018 18:50:08,03/26/2018 19:50:08,41874;5B 71-00-01 DISSA 005,03/26/2018 19:50:08,03/26/2018 20:50:08,41875;5B 71-00-01 DISSA 006,03/26/2018 20:50:08,03/26/2018 21:50:08,41876;5B 71-00-01 DISSA 007,03/26/2018 21:50:08,03/26/2018 22:50:08,41877;5B 71-00-01 DISSA 008,03/26/2018 22:50:08,03/26/2018 23:50:08,41878;CFM56-5B QEC CLEAN-001,03/26/2018 23:50:08,03/27/2018 03:50:08,41879;CFM56-5B QEC CLEAN-002,03/27/2018 03:50:08,03/27/2018 04:50:08,41880;CFM56-5B QEC CLEAN-003,03/27/2018 04:50:08,03/27/2018 05:50:08,41881;CFM56-5B QEC CLEAN-004,03/27/2018 05:50:08,03/27/2018 06:50:08,41882;CFM56-5B QEC CLEAN-005,03/27/2018 06:50:08,03/27/2018 07:50:08,41883;CFM56-5B QEC CLEAN-006,03/27/2018 07:50:08,03/27/2018 08:50:08,41884;ESM 72-00-02 LPT MAJOR MODULE,03/27/2018 08:50:08,03/27/2018 09:50:08,41885;ESM 72-00-02 FAN MAJOR MODULE,03/27/2018 09:50:08,03/27/2018 10:50:08,41886;ESM 72-00-02 CORE ENGINE,03/27/2018 10:50:08,03/27/2018 11:50:08,41887;ESM 72-00-02 CORE ENGINE MAJOR,03/27/2018 11:50:08,03/27/2018 12:50:08,41888;ESM 72-00-03 DISASSY 001 - LPT,03/27/2018 12:50:08,03/27/2018 13:50:08,41889;ESM 72-00-02 REMOVAL - FAN MM,03/27/2018 13:50:08,03/27/2018 14:50:08,41890;ESM 72-00-31 REMOVAL 001,03/27/2018 22:50:08,03/27/2018 23:50:08,41891;CFM ESM 72-21-05-01,03/27/2018 23:50:08,03/28/2018 00:50:08,41892;CFM ESM 72-21-05-02,03/28/2018 00:50:08,03/28/2018 01:50:08,41893;CFM ESM 72-21-05-11,03/28/2018 01:50:08,03/28/2018 02:50:08,41894;CFM ESM 72-21-05-03,03/28/2018 02:50:08,03/28/2018 03:50:08,41895;CFM ESM 72-21-05-04,03/28/2018 03:50:08,03/28/2018 04:50:08,41896;CFM ESM 72-21-05-05,03/28/2018 04:50:08,03/28/2018 05:50:08,41897;CFM ESM 72-21-05-06,03/28/2018 05:50:08,03/28/2018 06:50:08,41898;CFM ESM 72-21-05-07,03/28/2018 06:50:08,03/28/2018 07:50:08,41899;CFM ESM 72-21-05-08,03/28/2018 07:50:08,03/28/2018 08:50:08,41900;CFM ESM 72-21-05-09,03/28/2018 08:50:08,03/28/2018 09:50:08,41901;CFM ESM 72-21-05-10,03/28/2018 09:50:08,03/28/2018 10:50:08,41902;CFM SPM 70-63-15,03/28/2018 10:50:08,03/28/2018 11:50:08,41903;CMM 72-20-01 DVI,03/28/2018 11:50:08,03/28/2018 12:50:08,41904;CFM ESM 72-00-03-01,03/28/2018 12:50:08,03/28/2018 13:50:08,41905;CFM ESM 72-00-03-02,03/28/2018 13:50:08,03/28/2018 14:50:08,41906;CFM ESM 72-00-03-03,03/28/2018 14:50:08,03/28/2018 15:50:08,41907;CFM ESM 72-52-08,03/28/2018 15:50:08,03/28/2018 16:50:08,41908;CFM ESM 72-00-003,03/28/2018 16:50:08,03/28/2018 17:50:08,41909;CFM-5B NDT 72-00 FAN&BLADE,03/28/2018 17:50:08,03/28/2018 18:50:08,41910;CFM ESM 72-00-21-01,03/28/2018 18:50:08,03/28/2018 19:50:08,42211;CFM ESM 72-21-01-01,03/28/2018 19:50:08,03/28/2018 20:50:08,42212;CFM ESM 72-21-01-02,03/28/2018 20:50:08,03/28/2018 21:50:08,42213;CFM ESM 72-00-21-02,03/28/2018 21:50:08,03/28/2018 22:50:08,42214;CFM SPM 70-63-15-01,03/28/2018 22:50:08,03/28/2018 23:50:08,42215;CFM ESM 72-00-21-03,03/28/2018 23:50:08,03/29/2018 00:50:08,42216;CFM SPM 70-63-15-02,03/29/2018 00:50:08,03/29/2018 01:50:08,42217;CFM ESM 72-21-00/ ASS.001,03/29/2018 01:50:08,03/29/2018 02:50:08,42218;CFM ESM 72-21-13,03/29/2018 02:50:08,03/29/2018 03:50:08,42219;CFM ESM 72-21-00,03/29/2018 03:50:08,03/29/2018 04:50:08,42220;CFM SPM 70-63-15-03,03/29/2018 04:50:08,03/29/2018 05:50:08,42221;CFM CESM 001,03/29/2018 05:50:08,03/29/2018 06:50:08,42222;CFM SPM 70-63-15-04,03/29/2018 06:50:08,03/29/2018 07:50:08,42223;CFM ESM 72-21-06-01,03/29/2018 07:50:08,03/29/2018 09:50:08,42224;CFM ESM 72-21-06-02,03/29/2018 09:50:08,03/29/2018 10:50:08,42225;CFM SPM 70-63-15-05,03/29/2018 10:50:08,03/29/2018 11:50:08,42226;5B 72-00-21 CLEANING 001,03/29/2018 11:50:08,03/29/2018 12:50:08,42227;5B 72-21-01 FAN ROTOR BLADES,03/29/2018 12:50:08,03/29/2018 13:50:08,42228;5B 72-21-02 B BLADES, STG 2-5,03/29/2018 13:50:08,03/29/2018 14:50:08,42229;5B 72-21-03 FAN DISK ASSY,03/29/2018 14:50:08,03/29/2018 15:50:08,42230;5B 72-21-04 BOOSTER SPOOL,03/29/2018 15:50:08,03/29/2018 16:50:08,42231;5B 72-21-05 SPINNER FR CONE,03/29/2018 16:50:08,03/29/2018 17:50:08,42232;5B 72-21-05 SPIN R RE CONE,03/29/2018 17:50:08,03/29/2018 18:50:08,42233;5B 72-21-07 BOO STAGES 2-5,03/29/2018 18:50:08,03/29/2018 19:50:08,42234;5B 72-21-09 VANE ASSY, STG1&5,03/29/2018 19:50:08,03/29/2018 21:50:08,42235;5B 72-21-09 VANE ASSY STG2,3&4,03/29/2018 21:50:08,03/29/2018 22:50:08,42236;5B 72-21-10 FAN BLADE SPACERS,03/29/2018 22:50:08,03/29/2018 23:50:08,42237;5B 70-21-11 FAN&BOO BOLTS,03/29/2018 23:50:08,03/30/2018 00:50:08,42238;5B 72-00-23 CLEANING 001,03/30/2018 00:50:08,03/30/2018 01:50:08,42239;5B HAND CLEAN THE MODULE,03/30/2018 01:50:08,03/30/2018 02:50:08,42240;5B VACUUM CLE VBV CAVITIES,03/30/2018 02:50:08,03/30/2018 05:50:08,42241;5B 72-23-01 FAN FRAME,03/30/2018 05:50:08,03/30/2018 06:50:08,42242;5B 72-23-02 FAN CASE ASSY,03/30/2018 06:50:08,03/30/2018 07:50:08,42243;5B 72-23-03 FAN OUT,03/30/2018 07:50:08,03/30/2018 08:50:08,42244;5B 72-23-04 FAN OUTLET ASSY,03/30/2018 08:50:08,03/30/2018 09:50:08,42245;5B 72-23-05 HOUSINGS,03/30/2018 09:50:08,03/30/2018 10:50:08,42246;5B 72-23-05 IN&OUT,03/30/2018 10:50:08,03/30/2018 11:50:08,42247;5B 72-23-06 SELF BEARING,03/30/2018 11:50:08,03/30/2018 12:50:08,42248;5B 72-23-07 FAN DUCT PANELS,03/30/2018 12:50:08,03/30/2018 13:50:08,42249;5B 72-23-08 FAN CA CO PANELS,03/30/2018 13:50:08,03/30/2018 14:50:08,42250;5B 72-23-12 FAN FRAME,03/30/2018 14:50:08,03/30/2018 15:50:08,42251;5B 72-23-10 AGB,03/30/2018 15:50:08,03/30/2018 16:50:08,42252;5B 72-23-13 OIL AND AIR HOSES,03/30/2018 16:50:08,03/30/2018 17:50:08,42253;5B 72-23-14 ACCE,03/30/2018 17:50:08,03/30/2018 18:50:08,42254;5B 72-23-15 ADRIVE CLEVIS,03/30/2018 18:50:08,03/30/2018 20:50:08,42255;5B 72-23-16 VARI ROD,03/30/2018 20:50:08,03/30/2018 21:50:08,42256;5B 72-23-17 OIL T M PARTS,03/30/2018 21:50:08,03/30/2018 22:50:08,42257;5B 72-23-18 NO.3 DRAIN TUBE,03/30/2018 22:50:08,03/30/2018 23:50:08,42258;5B 72-23-19 NO. 3OIL SEAL,03/30/2018 23:50:08,03/31/2018 00:50:08,42259;5B 72-23-20 NO. 3BRG,03/31/2018 00:50:08,03/31/2018 01:50:08,42260;5B 72-23-21 ASSEMBLY,03/31/2018 01:50:08,03/31/2018 02:50:08,42261;5B 72-23-23 SPLITTER FAIRING,03/31/2018 02:50:08,03/31/2018 03:50:08,42262;5B 72-23-24 GUIDE TUBE,03/31/2018 03:50:08,03/31/2018 04:50:08,42263;5B 72-23-25 PLATE,03/31/2018 04:50:08,03/31/2018 05:50:08,42264;5B 72-23-26 AIR TUBE,03/31/2018 05:50:08,03/31/2018 06:50:08,42265;5B 72-23-27 AIR TUBE FLANGE,03/31/2018 06:50:08,03/31/2018 07:50:08,42266;5B 72-23-30 DOWN,03/31/2018 07:50:08,03/31/2018 08:50:08,42267;5B 72-23-35 FAN FR H.WARE,03/31/2018 08:50:08,03/31/2018 09:50:08,42268;5B 72-23-36 SCOOP CFIG 01,03/31/2018 09:50:08,03/31/2018 10:50:08,42269;5B 72-23-36 SCOOP CFIG 02,03/31/2018 10:50:08,03/31/2018 11:50:08,42270;5B 72-23-37 SLIDE,03/31/2018 11:50:08,03/31/2018 12:50:08,42271;72-53-00-440-001,03/31/2018 12:50:08,03/31/2018 13:50:08,41911;72-00-03-420-086/8,03/31/2018 13:50:08,03/31/2018 14:50:08,41912;148-CFM56-5 72-56-00 LPT,03/31/2018 14:50:08,03/31/2018 15:50:08,41913;72-54-00-430-162-1,03/31/2018 15:50:08,03/31/2018 17:50:08,41914;ROHR 71-00-17,03/31/2018 17:50:08,03/31/2018 18:50:08,41915;CFM ESM 72-00-004,03/31/2018 18:50:08,03/31/2018 19:50:08,41916;CFM ESM 72-55-16-01,03/31/2018 19:50:08,03/31/2018 20:50:08,41917;CFM ESM 72-55-16-02,03/31/2018 20:50:08,03/31/2018 21:50:08,41918;AC ESM 72-00-03 INST.001,03/31/2018 21:50:08,03/31/2018 22:50:08,41919;72-53-00-440-001-CLEAN,03/31/2018 22:50:08,03/31/2018 23:50:08,41920;72-53-00-440-001-NDT,03/31/2018 23:50:08,04/01/2018 00:50:08,41921;3-S-72-00-53 IR HPT SH -ST1 LP,04/01/2018 00:50:08,04/01/2018 01:50:08,41922;3-S-72-54-07 REP 001 LPT CASE,04/01/2018 01:50:08,04/01/2018 02:50:08,41923;3-S-753151GENREPMNRDFCTSTLPT,04/01/2018 02:50:08,04/01/2018 04:50:08,41924;3-S-753151GENREPSTLPTABRBLST,04/01/2018 04:50:08,04/01/2018 05:50:08,41925;72-55-14 4 BRG ROT.OIL SEAL.,04/01/2018 05:50:08,04/01/2018 06:50:08,42272;FIRST OPERATION-CLEAN-1,04/01/2018 06:50:08,04/01/2018 07:50:08,42273;LAST OPERATION-CLEAN-1,04/01/2018 07:50:08,04/01/2018 08:50:08,42274;72-54-11 LPT C. AIR TUBE ASSY,04/01/2018 08:50:08,04/01/2018 09:50:08,42275;72-54-13 LPT C. AIR MANIFOLDS.,04/01/2018 09:50:08,04/01/2018 10:50:08,42276;72-54-14LPT C.LING AIR.T.SUPP,04/01/2018 10:50:08,04/01/2018 11:50:08,42277;72-54-20 LPT HARDWARE,04/01/2018 11:50:08,04/01/2018 12:50:08,42278;72-55-20 HARDWARE.,04/01/2018 12:50:08,04/01/2018 15:50:08,42279;72-55-17 SLOTTED NUT,04/01/2018 15:50:08,04/01/2018 16:50:08,42280;72-55-16 LPT SHAFT PLUG ASSY.,04/01/2018 16:50:08,04/01/2018 17:50:08,42281;72-55-15 AIR/OIL SEP. & COVER.,04/01/2018 17:50:08,04/01/2018 18:50:08,42282;72-55-07 RETAINER NUTS,04/01/2018 18:50:08,04/01/2018 19:50:08,42283;72-56-06 OIL INLET COVER,04/01/2018 19:50:08,04/01/2018 20:50:08,42284;72-56-07 REAR COVER.,04/01/2018 20:50:08,04/01/2018 22:50:08,42285;72-56-08 FLAME ARR.ASSY,04/01/2018 22:50:08,04/01/2018 23:50:08,42286;72-56-20 TURBINE FRAME HARD.W,04/01/2018 23:50:08,04/02/2018 00:50:08,42287;3-S-72-00-03 LPT MM CLEAN,04/02/2018 00:50:08,04/02/2018 01:50:08,42288;72-54-04 LPT SHROUD SUPPORT-01,04/02/2018 01:50:08,04/02/2018 02:50:08,42289;72-54-04 LPT SHROUD SUPP.,04/02/2018 02:50:08,04/02/2018 03:50:08,42290;72-54-04 LPT SHROUD SUPPORT-02,04/02/2018 03:50:08,04/02/2018 04:50:08,42291;72-54-11 LPT COOLING AIR TUBE,04/02/2018 04:50:08,04/02/2018 05:50:08,42292;72-54-13 LPT COOLING AIR MANI,04/02/2018 05:50:08,04/02/2018 06:50:08,42293;72-54-14 LPT COOLI AIR TUBE,04/02/2018 06:50:08,04/02/2018 07:50:08,42294;72-55-07 RETAINER NUTS.,04/02/2018 07:50:08,04/02/2018 11:50:08,42295;72-55-15 A/O SEP AND COVER.,04/02/2018 11:50:08,04/02/2018 12:50:08,42296;72-55-16 LPT SHAFT PLUG ASSY,04/02/2018 12:50:08,04/02/2018 13:50:08,42297;72-55-17 SLOTTED NUT-NDT,04/02/2018 13:50:08,04/02/2018 14:50:08,42298;72-56-06 OIL INLET COVER-NDT,04/02/2018 14:50:08,04/02/2018 15:50:08,42299;72-56-07 REAR COVER.-NDT,04/02/2018 15:50:08,04/02/2018 16:50:08,42300;LAST OPERATION-NDT-1,04/02/2018 16:50:08,04/02/2018 17:50:08,42301;FIRST OPERATION-NDT-1,04/02/2018 17:50:08,04/02/2018 18:50:08,42302;72-55-14 NDT,04/02/2018 18:50:08,04/02/2018 19:50:08,42303;72-55-14 NO. 4 BEARING FWD ROT,04/02/2018 19:50:08,04/02/2018 20:50:08,42304;CFM ESM 72-00-63-01,04/02/2018 20:50:08,04/02/2018 21:50:08,41926;CFM ESM 72-00-63-02,04/02/2018 21:50:08,04/02/2018 22:50:08,41927;CFM ESM 72-00-63-03,04/02/2018 22:50:08,04/02/2018 23:50:08,41928;CFM ESM 72-00-63-04,04/02/2018 23:50:08,04/03/2018 00:50:08,41929;5B 726320 D SHAFT HOU,04/03/2018 00:50:08,04/03/2018 01:50:08,41930;5B 720902 AGB,04/03/2018 01:50:08,04/03/2018 02:50:08,41931;5B 726301 AGB HOUSING.,04/03/2018 02:50:08,04/03/2018 03:50:08,41932;5B 726302 AGB PADS,04/03/2018 03:50:08,04/03/2018 04:50:08,41933;5B 726303 G.SHAFT,04/03/2018 04:50:08,04/03/2018 05:50:08,41934;5B 726305 AGB LUB SHAFT,04/03/2018 05:50:08,04/03/2018 06:50:08,41935;5B 726308 MAG HOU,04/03/2018 06:50:08,04/03/2018 07:50:08,41936;5B 726311 AGB HAND SHAFT,04/03/2018 07:50:08,04/03/2018 08:50:08,41937;5B 726314 QAD ADA,04/03/2018 08:50:08,04/03/2018 09:50:08,41938;5B 726315 START,04/03/2018 09:50:08,04/03/2018 10:50:08,41939;5B 726316 AGB BRACKETS,04/03/2018 10:50:08,04/03/2018 11:50:08,41940;5B 726317 AGB D SHAFT,04/03/2018 11:50:08,04/03/2018 12:50:08,41941;5B 726318 AGB PINS,04/03/2018 12:50:08,04/03/2018 13:50:08,41942;5B 726313 V-CLAMP NDT,04/03/2018 13:50:08,04/03/2018 14:50:08,41943;72-00-62 TGB.MODULE CLEANING,04/03/2018 14:50:08,04/03/2018 15:50:08,42195;72-62-01 TGB HOUSING,04/03/2018 15:50:08,04/03/2018 16:50:08,42196;72-62-02 TGB B.G.SHAFTS,04/03/2018 16:50:08,04/03/2018 17:50:08,42197;72-62-04 TGB BRG SUPP.,04/03/2018 17:50:08,04/03/2018 18:50:08,42198;72-62-05 TGB BRG NUTS,04/03/2018 18:50:08,04/03/2018 19:50:08,42199;72-62-06 TGB R.&.HORIZ.D.S,04/03/2018 19:50:08,04/03/2018 20:50:08,42200;72-62-07 TGB H.D.S.HOUSING,04/03/2018 20:50:08,04/03/2018 21:50:08,42201;72-62-08 TGB.H.D.S.H.SLEEVE,04/03/2018 21:50:08,04/03/2018 22:50:08,42202;72-62-09 TGB OIL DISTRIBUTORS,04/03/2018 22:50:08,04/03/2018 23:50:08,42203;72-62-11 TGB OIL NOZ.PLUGS,04/03/2018 23:50:08,04/04/2018 00:50:08,42204;72-62-12 TGB LOCKING NUT.,04/04/2018 00:50:08,04/04/2018 01:50:08,42205;72-62-13 TGB CLAMP,04/04/2018 01:50:08,04/04/2018 02:50:08,42206;72-62-14 TGB TAB WASHERS,04/04/2018 02:50:08,04/04/2018 03:50:08,42207;72-62-20 TGB HARDWARE,04/04/2018 03:50:08,04/04/2018 04:50:08,42208;72-09-01 M.ENG.&GB BRG,04/04/2018 04:50:08,04/04/2018 05:50:08,42209;72-09-02 M.ENG&GB.O.NOZZLE,04/04/2018 05:50:08,04/04/2018 06:50:08,42210;CMM 26-10-63,04/04/2018 06:50:08,04/04/2018 07:50:08,41944;AMM 26-12-00,04/04/2018 07:50:08,04/04/2018 08:50:08,41945;CMM 26-10-63/-65,04/04/2018 08:50:08,04/04/2018 09:50:08,41946;ROHR 71-00-17-01,04/04/2018 09:50:08,04/04/2018 10:50:08,41947;CFM ESM 72-09-03-01,04/04/2018 10:50:08,04/04/2018 11:50:08,41948;CFM ESM 72-09-03-02,04/04/2018 11:50:08,04/04/2018 12:50:08,41949;ROHR 71-00-17-02,04/04/2018 12:50:08,04/04/2018 13:50:08,41950;CMM 79-11-16,04/04/2018 13:50:08,04/04/2018 14:50:08,41951;CFM ESM 72-23-17,04/04/2018 14:50:08,04/04/2018 15:50:08,41952;CMM 77-21-13-01,04/04/2018 15:50:08,04/04/2018 16:50:08,41953;CMM 77-21-13-02,04/04/2018 16:50:08,04/04/2018 17:50:08,41954;CMM 77-21-13-03,04/04/2018 17:50:08,04/04/2018 18:50:08,41955;CFM ESM 72-09-03-03,04/04/2018 18:50:08,04/04/2018 19:50:08,41956;ESM 71-09-00 INSP-001,04/04/2018 19:50:08,04/04/2018 20:50:08,41957;ROHR CMM 78-11-05, REPAIR 002,04/04/2018 20:50:08,04/04/2018 21:50:08,41958;ROHR CMM 71-50-00-01,04/04/2018 21:50:08,04/04/2018 22:50:08,41959;CFM ESM 72-56-06-01,04/04/2018 22:50:08,04/04/2018 23:50:08,41960;CFM ESM 72-56-06-02,04/04/2018 23:50:08,04/05/2018 00:50:08,41961;ROHR CMM 71-50-00-02,04/05/2018 00:50:08,04/05/2018 01:50:08,41962;ROHR CMM 71-50-00-03,04/05/2018 01:50:08,04/05/2018 02:50:08,41963;ESM 72-09-00-01,04/05/2018 02:50:08,04/05/2018 03:50:08,41964;ESM 72-09-00-02,04/05/2018 03:50:08,04/05/2018 04:50:08,41965;ROHR 71-00-17-03,04/05/2018 04:50:08,04/05/2018 05:50:08,41966;ROHR 71-00-17-04,04/05/2018 05:50:08,04/05/2018 06:50:08,41967;ROHR CMM 78-11-05,04/05/2018 06:50:08,04/05/2018 07:50:08,41968;CMM 74-21-15-01,04/05/2018 07:50:08,04/05/2018 08:50:08,41969;CMM 74-21-15-02,04/05/2018 08:50:08,04/05/2018 09:50:08,41970;ROHR 71-00-17-06,04/05/2018 09:50:08,04/05/2018 10:50:08,41971;CMM 71-00-17-01,04/05/2018 10:50:08,04/05/2018 11:50:08,41972;CMM 71-00-17-02,04/05/2018 11:50:08,04/05/2018 12:50:08,41973;CFM ESM 72-00-00,04/05/2018 12:50:08,04/05/2018 13:50:08,41974;CFM SPM 70-70-00,04/05/2018 13:50:08,04/05/2018 14:50:08,41975;CFM ESM 72-61-02,04/05/2018 14:50:08,04/05/2018 15:50:08,41976;72-00-03-420-054-01,04/05/2018 15:50:08,04/05/2018 16:50:08,41977;CFM ESM 72-54-07,04/05/2018 16:50:08,04/05/2018 17:50:08,41978;CFM ESM 72-53-02,04/05/2018 17:50:08,04/05/2018 18:50:08,41979;018-CFM56-3 COREMM FULL ASSY,04/05/2018 18:50:08,04/05/2018 19:50:08,41980;075-CFM56-3 72-31-00 ASSY-01,04/05/2018 19:50:08,04/05/2018 20:50:08,41981;CFM56-5-51X MODULE ASSY,04/05/2018 20:50:08,04/05/2018 21:50:08,41982;075-CFM56-3 72-31-00 ASSY-02,04/05/2018 21:50:08,04/05/2018 22:50:08,41983;TASK 72-00-01-430-001-3-8,04/05/2018 22:50:08,04/05/2018 23:50:08,41984;152A-ENG QEC EXT BUILD-UP,04/05/2018 23:50:08,04/06/2018 00:50:08,41985;ENGINE ASSEMBLY,04/06/2018 00:50:08,04/06/2018 01:50:08,41986;AMM 24-21-00-01,04/06/2018 01:50:08,04/06/2018 02:50:08,41987;AMM 24-21-00-05,04/06/2018 02:50:08,04/06/2018 03:50:08,41988;AMM 29-10-00-08,04/06/2018 03:50:08,04/06/2018 04:50:08,41989;AMM 73-11-10-09,04/06/2018 04:50:08,04/06/2018 05:50:08,41990;AMM 79-21-10-15,04/06/2018 05:50:08,04/06/2018 06:50:08,41991;AMM 79-21-10-16,04/06/2018 06:50:08,04/06/2018 07:50:08,41992;TASK 72-00-02-420-001-17,04/06/2018 07:50:08,04/06/2018 08:50:08,41993;72-00-02-420-060/1-18,04/06/2018 08:50:08,04/06/2018 09:50:08,41994;72-00-02-420-060/2-19,04/06/2018 09:50:08,04/06/2018 10:50:08,41995;72-00-02-420-060/3-20,04/06/2018 10:50:08,04/06/2018 11:50:08,41996;72-00-02-420-001,04/06/2018 11:50:08,04/06/2018 12:50:08,41997;72-00-02-420-051,04/06/2018 12:50:08,04/06/2018 13:50:08,41998;72-00-02-420-058,04/06/2018 13:50:08,04/06/2018 14:50:08,41999;72-00-02-420-062,04/06/2018 14:50:08,04/06/2018 15:50:08,42000;72-52-00-440-061/1,04/06/2018 15:50:08,04/06/2018 16:50:08,42001;72-00-02-420-062/2,04/06/2018 16:50:08,04/06/2018 17:50:08,42002;72-00-02-420-062/3,04/06/2018 17:50:08,04/06/2018 18:50:08,42003;72-00-02-420-062/4,04/06/2018 18:50:08,04/06/2018 19:50:08,42004;72-00-02-420-062/5,04/06/2018 19:50:08,04/06/2018 20:50:08,42005;72-00-02-420-183,04/06/2018 20:50:08,04/06/2018 21:50:08,42006;72-00-02-420-060/1-31,04/06/2018 21:50:08,04/06/2018 22:50:08,42007;72-00-02-420-060/2-32,04/06/2018 22:50:08,04/06/2018 23:50:08,42008;72-00-02-420-060/3-33,04/06/2018 23:50:08,04/07/2018 00:50:08,42009;72-00-02-420-060/4,04/07/2018 00:50:08,04/07/2018 01:50:08,42010;72-00-02-420-060/5,04/07/2018 01:50:08,04/07/2018 02:50:08,42011;72-00-02-420-060/6-1,04/07/2018 02:50:08,04/07/2018 03:50:08,42012;72-00-02-420-060/7,04/07/2018 03:50:08,04/07/2018 04:50:08,42013;72-00-02-420-060,04/07/2018 04:50:08,04/07/2018 05:50:08,42014;72-00-02-420-061,04/07/2018 05:50:08,04/07/2018 06:50:08,42015;TASK 72-00-02-420-001-40,04/07/2018 06:50:08,04/07/2018 07:50:08,42016;72-23-00-440-065,04/07/2018 07:50:08,04/07/2018 08:50:08,42017;72-23-00-440-068-1,04/07/2018 08:50:08,04/07/2018 09:50:08,42018;72-23-00-440-072-1-A,04/07/2018 09:50:08,04/07/2018 10:50:08,42019;72-23-00-440-072-1-B,04/07/2018 10:50:08,04/07/2018 11:50:08,42020;TASK 72-23-00-440-004-1,04/07/2018 11:50:08,04/07/2018 12:50:08,42021;72-54-00-430-162-2-46,04/07/2018 12:50:08,04/07/2018 13:50:08,42022;72-54-00-430-162-2-47,04/07/2018 13:50:08,04/07/2018 14:50:08,42023;72-00-00-420-182/2-48,04/07/2018 14:50:08,04/07/2018 15:50:08,42024;72-00-00-420-182/3-49,04/07/2018 15:50:08,04/07/2018 16:50:08,42025;72-00-00-420-188-50,04/07/2018 16:50:08,04/07/2018 17:50:08,42026;72-00-00-420-189-51,04/07/2018 17:50:08,04/07/2018 18:50:08,42027;72-00-00-420-181-1-52,04/07/2018 18:50:08,04/07/2018 19:50:08,42028;72-00-00-420-182-53,04/07/2018 19:50:08,04/07/2018 20:50:08,42029;72-00-00-420-182/1-54,04/07/2018 20:50:08,04/07/2018 21:50:08,42030;72-00-00-420-182/1-55,04/07/2018 21:50:08,04/07/2018 22:50:08,42031;72-00-00-420-182/2-56,04/07/2018 22:50:08,04/07/2018 23:50:08,42032;72-00-00-420-182/3-57,04/07/2018 23:50:08,04/08/2018 00:50:08,42033;72-00-00-420-188-58,04/08/2018 00:50:08,04/08/2018 01:50:08,42034;72-00-00-420-189-59,04/08/2018 01:50:08,04/08/2018 02:50:08,42035;72-00-00-420-181-1-60,04/08/2018 02:50:08,04/08/2018 03:50:08,42036;72-00-00-420-182-61,04/08/2018 03:50:08,04/08/2018 04:50:08,42037;72-00-00-420-052-62,04/08/2018 04:50:08,04/08/2018 05:50:08,42038;72-00-00-420-052/1-63,04/08/2018 05:50:08,04/08/2018 06:50:08,42039;72-00-00-420-255-64,04/08/2018 06:50:08,04/08/2018 07:50:08,42040;TASK 72-00-00-420-006-65,04/08/2018 07:50:08,04/08/2018 08:50:08,42041;TASK 72-00-00-420-006-001-66,04/08/2018 08:50:08,04/08/2018 09:50:08,42042;TASK 72-00-00-420-006-001CON-6,04/08/2018 09:50:08,04/08/2018 10:50:08,42043;72-00-00-420-052-68,04/08/2018 10:50:08,04/08/2018 11:50:08,42044;72-00-00-420-052/1-69,04/08/2018 11:50:08,04/08/2018 12:50:08,42045;72-00-00-420-255-70,04/08/2018 12:50:08,04/08/2018 13:50:08,42046;TASK 72-00-00-420-006-71,04/08/2018 13:50:08,04/08/2018 14:50:08,42047;TASK 72-00-00-420-006-001-72,04/08/2018 14:50:08,04/08/2018 15:50:08,42048;TASK 72-00-00-420-006-001CON-7,04/08/2018 15:50:08,04/08/2018 16:50:08,42049;72-00-00-420-098-74,04/08/2018 16:50:08,04/08/2018 17:50:08,42050;72-00-00-420-276,04/08/2018 17:50:08,04/08/2018 18:50:08,42051;TASK 72-00-00-430-008-76,04/08/2018 18:50:08,04/08/2018 19:50:08,42052;72-00-00-420-098-77,04/08/2018 19:50:08,04/08/2018 20:50:08,42053;TASK 72-00-00-430-008-78,04/08/2018 20:50:08,04/08/2018 21:50:08,42054;72-00-00-420-101-79,04/08/2018 21:50:08,04/08/2018 22:50:08,42055;72-00-00-420-129-80,04/08/2018 22:50:08,04/08/2018 23:50:08,42056;72-00-00-420-142-81,04/08/2018 23:50:08,04/09/2018 00:50:08,42057;72-00-00-420-270-82,04/09/2018 00:50:08,04/09/2018 01:50:08,42058;72-00-00-420-275-83,04/09/2018 01:50:08,04/09/2018 02:50:08,42059;72-00-00-420-129-84,04/09/2018 02:50:08,04/09/2018 03:50:08,42060;72-00-00-420-142-85,04/09/2018 03:50:08,04/09/2018 04:50:08,42061;72-00-00-420-270-86,04/09/2018 04:50:08,04/09/2018 05:50:08,42062;72-00-00-420-275-87,04/09/2018 05:50:08,04/09/2018 06:50:08,42063;72-00-00-420-101-88,04/09/2018 06:50:08,04/09/2018 07:50:08,42064;72-00-00-420-053-89,04/09/2018 07:50:08,04/09/2018 08:50:08,42065;72-00-00-420-055-90,04/09/2018 08:50:08,04/09/2018 09:50:08,42066;TASK 72-00-00-420-009-91,04/09/2018 09:50:08,04/09/2018 10:50:08,42067;72-00-00-420-053-92,04/09/2018 10:50:08,04/09/2018 11:50:08,42068;72-00-00-420-055-93,04/09/2018 11:50:08,04/09/2018 12:50:08,42069;TASK 72-00-00-420-009-94,04/09/2018 12:50:08,04/09/2018 13:50:08,42070;72-00-01-430-073-95,04/09/2018 13:50:08,04/09/2018 14:50:08,42071;72-00-01-430-073/1-96,04/09/2018 14:50:08,04/09/2018 15:50:08,42072;72-00-01-430-073/2-97,04/09/2018 15:50:08,04/09/2018 16:50:08,42073;TASK 72-00-01-430-001-3-98,04/09/2018 16:50:08,04/09/2018 17:50:08,42074;72-00-01-430-073-99,04/09/2018 17:50:08,04/09/2018 18:50:08,42075;72-00-01-430-073/1-100,04/09/2018 18:50:08,04/09/2018 19:50:08,42076;72-00-01-430-073/2-101,04/09/2018 19:50:08,04/09/2018 20:50:08,42077;TASK 72-00-01-430-001-3-102,04/09/2018 20:50:08,04/09/2018 21:50:08,42078;72-00-01-430-073-1,04/09/2018 21:50:08,04/09/2018 
22:50:08,42079;72-00-03-420-051-104,04/09/2018 22:50:08,04/09/2018 23:50:08,42080;72-00-02-420-060/2-105,04/09/2018 23:50:08,04/10/2018 00:50:08,42081;72-00-03-420-086/4-106,04/10/2018 
00:50:08,04/10/2018 01:50:08,42082;72-00-03-420-086/7-107,04/10/2018 01:50:08,04/10/2018 02:50:08,42083;72-00-03-420-086/8-108,04/10/2018 02:50:08,04/10/2018 
03:50:08,42084;72-00-03-420-086/9-109,04/10/2018 03:50:08,04/10/2018 04:50:08,42085;TASK 72-00-03-420-001-110,04/10/2018 04:50:08,04/10/2018 05:50:08,42086;72-00-03-420-086-111,04/10/2018 
05:50:08,04/10/2018 06:50:08,42087;72-00-03-420-086/1-112,04/10/2018 06:50:08,04/10/2018 07:50:08,42088;72-00-03-420-086/10-113,04/10/2018 07:50:08,04/10/2018 
08:50:08,42089;72-00-03-420-086/11-114,04/10/2018 08:50:08,04/10/2018 09:50:08,42090;72-00-03-420-086/2-115,04/10/2018 09:50:08,04/10/2018 10:50:08,42091;72-00-03-420-086/3-116,04/10/2018 
10:50:08,04/10/2018 11:50:08,42092;72-00-03-420-086/4-117,04/10/2018 11:50:08,04/10/2018 12:50:08,42093;72-00-03-420-086/5-118,04/10/2018 12:50:08,04/10/2018 
13:50:08,42094;72-00-03-420-086/6-119,04/10/2018 13:50:08,04/10/2018 14:50:08,42095;72-00-03-420-086/1-120,04/10/2018 14:50:08,04/10/2018 15:50:08,42096;72-00-03-420-086/10-121,04/10/2018 
15:50:08,04/10/2018 16:50:08,42097;72-00-03-420-086/11-122,04/10/2018 16:50:08,04/10/2018 17:50:08,42098;72-00-03-420-086/2-123,04/10/2018 17:50:08,04/10/2018 
18:50:08,42099;72-00-03-420-086/3-124,04/10/2018 18:50:08,04/10/2018 19:50:08,42100;72-00-03-420-086/4-125,04/10/2018 19:50:08,04/10/2018 20:50:08,42101;72-00-03-420-086/5-126,04/10/2018 
20:50:08,04/10/2018 21:50:08,42102;72-00-03-420-051-127,04/10/2018 21:50:08,04/10/2018 22:50:08,42103;72-00-03-420-054,04/10/2018 22:50:08,04/10/2018 
23:50:08,42104;72-00-03-420-086-129,04/10/2018 23:50:08,04/11/2018 00:50:08,42105;72-00-03-420-086/6-130,04/11/2018 00:50:08,04/11/2018 01:50:08,42106;72-00-03-420-086/7-131,04/11/2018 01:50:08,04/11/2018 02:50:08,42107;72-00-03-420-086/8-132,04/11/2018 02:50:08,04/11/2018 04:50:08,42108;72-00-03-420-086/9-133,04/11/2018 04:50:08,04/11/2018 05:50:08,42109;72-00-03-420-086/ADD,04/11/2018 05:50:08,04/11/2018 06:50:08,42110;TASK 72-00-03-420-001-135,04/11/2018 06:50:08,04/11/2018 07:50:08,42111;72-00-21-420-136,04/11/2018 07:50:08,04/11/2018 08:50:08,42112;72-00-03-420-064-137,04/11/2018 08:50:08,04/11/2018 09:50:08,42113;72-00-03-420-064/1-138,04/11/2018 09:50:08,04/11/2018 10:50:08,42114;72-00-03-420-073-139,04/11/2018 10:50:08,04/11/2018 11:50:08,42115;72-00-03-420-070-140,04/11/2018 11:50:08,04/11/2018 12:50:08,42116;72-00-03-420-080-141,04/11/2018 12:50:08,04/11/2018 13:50:08,42117;72-00-03-420-083/1-142,04/11/2018 13:50:08,04/11/2018 14:50:08,42118;72-00-03-420-083/2-143,04/11/2018 14:50:08,04/11/2018 15:50:08,42119;72-00-03-420-087-144,04/11/2018 15:50:08,04/11/2018 16:50:08,42120;72-00-03-420-070-145,04/11/2018 16:50:08,04/11/2018 17:50:08,42121;72-00-03-420-080-146,04/11/2018 17:50:08,04/11/2018 18:50:08,42122;72-00-03-420-081,04/11/2018 18:50:08,04/11/2018 19:50:08,42123;72-00-03-420-081/1,04/11/2018 19:50:08,04/11/2018 20:50:08,42124;72-00-03-420-082,04/11/2018 20:50:08,04/11/2018 21:50:08,42125;72-00-03-420-083,04/11/2018 21:50:08,04/11/2018 22:50:08,42126;72-00-03-420-083/1-151,04/11/2018 22:50:08,04/11/2018 23:50:08,42127;72-00-21-420-152,04/11/2018 23:50:08,04/12/2018 00:50:08,42128;72-00-03-420-064-153,04/12/2018 00:50:08,04/12/2018 01:50:08,42129;72-00-03-420-064/1-154,04/12/2018 01:50:08,04/12/2018 02:50:08,42130;72-00-03-420-083/2-155,04/12/2018 02:50:08,04/12/2018 03:50:08,42131;72-00-03-420-087-156,04/12/2018 03:50:08,04/12/2018 04:50:08,42132;72-00-03-420-073-157,04/12/2018 04:50:08,04/12/2018 05:50:08,42133;72-00-63-420-055,04/12/2018 05:50:08,04/12/2018 06:50:08,42134;QEC EXT BP  INS TASK 01,04/12/2018 06:50:08,04/12/2018 07:50:08,42165;QEC EXT BP  INS TASK 02,04/12/2018 07:50:08,04/12/2018 08:50:08,42166;QEC EXT BP  INS TASK 03,04/12/2018 08:50:08,04/12/2018 09:50:08,42167;QEC EXT BP  INS 
TASK 04,04/12/2018 09:50:08,04/12/2018 10:50:08,42168;QEC EXT BP  INS TASK 05,04/12/2018 10:50:08,04/12/2018 11:50:08,42169;QEC EXT BP  INS TASK 06-01,04/12/2018 11:50:08,04/12/2018 
12:50:08,42170;QEC EXT BP  INS TASK 07,04/12/2018 12:50:08,04/12/2018 13:50:08,42171;QEC EXT BP  INS TASK 08,04/12/2018 13:50:08,04/12/2018 14:50:08,42172;QEC EXT BP  INS TASK 09,04/12/2018 
14:50:08,04/12/2018 15:50:08,42173;QEC EXT BP  INS TASK 10,04/12/2018 15:50:08,04/12/2018 16:50:08,42174;QEC EXT BP  INS TASK 11,04/12/2018 16:50:08,04/12/2018 17:50:08,42175;QEC EXT BP  INS 
TASK 12,04/12/2018 17:50:08,04/12/2018 18:50:08,42176;QEC EXT BP  INS TASK 13,04/12/2018 18:50:08,04/12/2018 19:50:08,42177;QEC EXT BP  INS TASK 14,04/12/2018 19:50:08,04/12/2018 
21:50:08,42178;QEC EXT BP  INS TASK 15,04/12/2018 21:50:08,04/12/2018 22:50:08,42179;QEC EXT BP  INS TASK 16,04/12/2018 22:50:08,04/12/2018 23:50:08,42180;QEC EXT BP  INS TASK 17,04/12/2018 
23:50:08,04/13/2018 00:50:08,42181;QEC EXT BP  INS TASK 18,04/13/2018 00:50:08,04/13/2018 01:50:08,42182;QEC EXT BP  INS TASK 19,04/13/2018 01:50:08,04/13/2018 02:50:08,42183;QEC EXT BP  INS 
TASK 20,04/13/2018 02:50:08,04/13/2018 03:50:08,42184;QEC EXT BP  INS TASK 21,04/13/2018 03:50:08,04/13/2018 06:50:08,42185;QEC EXT BP  INS TASK 22,04/13/2018 06:50:08,04/13/2018 
07:50:08,42186;151-CFM56-3 ENGINE M ASSY,04/13/2018 07:50:08,04/13/2018 08:50:08,42187;QEC EXT BP  INS TASK 06-02,04/13/2018 08:50:08,04/13/2018 09:50:08,42188;BCMM 71-21-13 FITTING 
ASSY,04/13/2018 09:50:08,04/13/2018 10:50:08,42189;CMM 54-42-12,04/13/2018 10:50:08,04/13/2018 11:50:08,42190;CMM 54-40-04,04/13/2018 11:50:08,04/13/2018 12:50:08,42191;CMM 54-50-01 X BEAM 
ASSY,04/13/2018 12:50:08,04/13/2018 13:50:08,42192;CMM 71-20-46 FWD BARRY,04/13/2018 13:50:08,04/13/2018 15:50:08,42193;CMM 54-40-04 AFT LORD,04/13/2018 15:50:08,04/13/2018 
16:50:08,42194;72-00-00 TEST-001,04/13/2018 16:50:08,04/13/2018 17:50:08,42135;CFM-5B - INSP-001,04/13/2018 17:50:08,04/13/2018 18:50:08,42136;CFM-5B - INSP-002,04/13/2018 18:50:08,04/13/2018 19:50:08,42137;72-00-00 TEST-002,04/13/2018 19:50:08,04/13/2018 20:50:08,42138;72-00-00 TEST-003,04/13/2018 20:50:08,04/13/2018 22:50:08,42139;72-00-00 
TEST-004,04/13/2018 22:50:08,04/13/2018 23:50:08,42140;72-00-00 TEST-005,04/13/2018 23:50:08,04/14/2018 00:50:08,42141;72-00-00 TEST-006,04/14/2018 00:50:08,04/14/2018 01:50:08,42142;72-00-00 TEST-007,04/14/2018 01:50:08,04/14/2018 02:50:08,42143;72-00-00 TEST-008,04/14/2018 02:50:08,04/14/2018 03:50:08,42144;CFM-5B-FIN INSP,04/14/2018 03:50:08,04/14/2018 04:50:08,42145;AMM 24-21-00,04/14/2018 04:50:08,04/14/2018 05:50:08,42146;AMM 29-10-00,04/14/2018 05:50:08,04/14/2018 06:50:08,42147;AMM 73-11-10,04/14/2018 06:50:08,04/14/2018 07:50:08,42148;AMM 79-21-10,04/14/2018 07:50:08,04/14/2018 08:50:08,42149;AMM 79-21-11,04/14/2018 08:50:08,04/14/2018 09:50:08,42150;72-00-00 CFM-5B - PREP SHIP-01,04/14/2018 09:50:08,04/14/2018 10:50:08,42151;72-00-00 CFM-5B - PREP SHIP-02,04/14/2018 10:50:08,04/14/2018 11:50:08,42152;72-00-00 CFM-5B - PREP SHIP-03,04/14/2018 11:50:08,04/14/2018 12:50:08,42153;72-00-00 CFM-5B - PREP SHIP-04,04/14/2018 12:50:08,04/14/2018 13:50:08,42154;72-00-00 CFM-5B - PREP SHIP-05,04/14/2018 13:50:08,04/14/2018 14:50:08,42155;72-00-00 CFM-5B - PREP SHIP-06,04/14/2018 14:50:08,04/14/2018 15:50:08,42156;'

SELECT 
     Split.a.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(max)') AS String  
 FROM  (SELECT  
         CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(@InputData, ';', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS String  
     ) AS A CROSS APPLY String.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps a little adjustment (safe characters).  The **RetSeq** is optional, but I like having it

**Example**

```
Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
      ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')))
 From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(@InputData,';','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
 Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
```

**Returns**

```
RetSeq  RetVal
    1   5B 71-00-01 DISSA 001,03/26/2018 15:50:08,03/26/2018 16:50:08,41871
    2   5B 71-00-01 DISSA 002,03/26/2018 16:50:08,03/26/2018 17:50:08,41872
    3   5B 71-00-01 DISSA 003,03/26/2018 17:50:08,03/26/2018 18:50:08,41873
    4   5B 71-00-01 DISSA 004,03/26/2018 18:50:08,03/26/2018 19:50:08,41874
    5   5B 71-00-01 DISSA 005,03/26/2018 19:50:08,03/26/2018 20:50:08,41875
    6   5B 71-00-01 DISSA 006,03/26/2018 20:50:08,03/26/2018 21:50:08,41876
    ...
  424   72-00-00 CFM-5B - PREP SHIP-04,04/14/2018 12:50:08,04/14/2018 13:50:08,42154
  425   72-00-00 CFM-5B - PREP SHIP-05,04/14/2018 13:50:08,04/14/2018 14:50:08,42155
  426   72-00-00 CFM-5B - PREP SHIP-06,04/14/2018 14:50:08,04/14/2018 15:50:08,42156
```

Comment: Argument data type xml is invalid for argument 1 of replace function.

Comment: Argument data type xml is invalid for argument 1 of replace function. AM  getting this error. when i use this query .haps a little adjustment (safe characters). The RetSeq is optional, but I like having it

Example

Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
      ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
 From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(@InputData,';','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
 Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)

Comment: @DanielStephen I can't replicate your error.  Is your data different than the sample provided?

Comment: No am using the same data which i provided to you. using SQL server 2014.. I tired to remove the row number but the error exists

Comment: Sorry  John, I got the issue. Now it is working . thanks a lot . :)